# C++ operator compilation error

Tags: c++, xcode, operator-overloading, llvm

I'm trying to compile a project which uses OpenCV C++ code in Xcode.

```
template<typename _Tp> inline MatND_<_Tp>& MatND_<_Tp>::operator = (const MatND& m)
{
    if( DataType<_Tp>::type == m.type() )
    {
        Mat::operator = (m);
        return *this;
    }
    if( DataType<_Tp>::depth == m.depth() )
    {
        return (*this = m.reshape(DataType<_Tp>::channels));
    }
    CV_DbgAssert(DataType<_Tp>::channels == m.channels());
    m.convertTo(*this, DataType<_Tp>::type);
    return *this;
}
```

Here it gives me a compiler error "Call to non-static member function without an object argument" on line "Mat::operator = (m);"

The code is not corrupt, I verified it [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/include/opencv/cxmat.hpp?rev=2264#L590).

Another interesting this is that, if I choose the compiler as LLVM GCC 4.2 then the code works fine, but I get this error when compiling with Apple LLVM compiler 3.2. I need to compile with Apple LLVM compiler since compiling with GCC is creating other problems.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

this->Mat::operator = (m);

When you are inside a templated member function, the compiler doesn't know what your base class is.  It just looks like you are trying to call a static member function, but Mat::operator=() isn't static, so it gives you that error.  By using this->Mat::operator=(m), the compiler now knows that you are actually trying to call a non-static member function.

With older compilers, there was less checking of templates when they were first encountered.  They were largely just stored as a big sequence of tokens and only when the template was instantiated was any checking done.  The C++ standard now requires that templates have a certain amount of checking done before they are instantiated, which makes certain tricks like this necessary.

Comment: That's actually not true. The problem you describe would only applies to non-qualified names. Using a qualified name like `Mat::operator =` is one way to *solve* this problem. Using `this->` is another way to solve this problem. There's no need to use both.

Comment: What is the right way to solve this problem? this->Mat::operator solved the compilation issue alright. Should I not use this solution?

Comment: @ameyazing: If it works, use it, but this must be a bug in the compiler. You shouldn't need `this->` here, if `MatND_` inherits from `Mat`.

Comment: @AndreyT: I think you are right.  As far as I can determine, before instantiation the compiler is only responsible for binding to the proper names and checking syntax.  Whether it calls Mat::operator= as a static or non-static member function is a semantic issue.